# loop to create validation scripts for 10 forms

Tags: jquery, forms, loops, validation

Is there a way to use a loop to create 10 of these, incrementing everywhere that has a "1"

```
//1
$('#catbudgetform1').validate({
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},

   rules: {budgTotal1: { required: true, money:true }},

   submitHandler:function() {
      var theForm = $('#catbudgetform1');
      updateSuccess(theForm,1);
   },

   invalidHandler: function(){
      alert('Valid Number (ex. 1234 or 1234.00) is Required');
   }
});
```

**notice #catbudgetform1 and budgTotal1 would need to be #catbudgetform2 and budgTotal2 and so on and so forth

OR is there a way to write this, that it would apply validation to each of the ten forms independently, but without writing it ten times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to do it only with classes, no ids, and in `submitHandler` use `$(this).closest("form")` instead of `$("#catbudgetform1")`

```
$('.catbudgetform').each(function(i){
   $(this).validate({
       errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},

       rules: {"budgTotal" + i: { required: true, money:true }},

       submitHandler:function() {
          var theForm = $(this).parents("form");
          updateSuccess(theForm,i);
       },

       invalidHandler: function(){
          alert('Valid Number (ex. 1234 or 1234.00) is Required');
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: It is a better approach, gets an upvote even if it doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Flocsy I tried to use a class $('.catbudgetform').validate() but then it is validating all of them at the same time. I couldn't figure out how to validate only the one I was submitting.

Comment: @livinzlife It takes more than just calling `$('.catbudgetform').validate()`, you have to make the call to validate smarter so that it figures out what the index is

Answer (score 1):

A much easier approach to this problem would be to change the elements from having a unique ID to having a particular class.  This greatly simplifies your logic because a class allows for a grouping which is what you want here.

```
$('.catbudgetform').each(function (index) {
   var theRules = {};
   theRules['budgTotal' + index] = { required: true, money:true };

   $(this).validate({
       errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},

       rules: theRules,

       submitHandler:function() {
          var theForm = $(this);
          updateSuccess(theForm, index);
       },

       invalidHandler: function(){
          alert('Valid Number (ex. 1234 or 1234.00) is Required');
       }  
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do something like what Flöcsy suggested, but since it sounds like you already have a bit of code that has that index harcoded in it, the following would do it.

```
for (var i=1; i <= 10; i++) {
    // Freeze the loop variable with a self calling function
    (function(index){
        // Can't do a literal object if the property is dynamic
        var rules = {};
        rules['budgTotal'+index] = { required: true, money:true };
        $('#catbudgetform' + index).validate({

            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {},

            rules: rules,

            submitHandler:function() {
                var theForm = $('#catbudgetform' + index);
                updateSuccess(theForm,index);
            },

            invalidHandler: function(){
                alert('Valid Number (ex. 1234 or 1234.00) is Required');
            }
        });
    })(i); // Passing the loop variable into the anonymous self calling function
}
```